# Why does this quadratic expression have three zeroes?

Tags: roots, quadratics

Why does this quadratic expression have three zeroes? I understand that when coefficient of $x^2$, coefficient of $x$, and constant term becomes zero, it becomes an identity and has infinitely many solutions (when equates to zero). 
But this quadratic expression, it’s coefficients are very small, but they are definitely not equal to zero. Why does this expression have three zeroes then?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't: $2.5^2 - 5 \times 2.5 + 6 = -1/4 \neq 0$.

Comment: Try $ 0.001\left(x\cdot x-5x+6\right)=0$ instead

Comment: It doesn't.  I think the software is trying to show two zeros and the vertex.  But the vertex is sufficiently close to 0 (it is -0.0025), that it has rounded to 0 in the display.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I just plugged in 2.5 for $x$ and got (-0.00025) I got confused when I first saw this. Because our maths teacher recently taught us about identities (when all the coefficients are zero).

Comment: If in doubt, zoom in! Desmos has pretty good resolution and will warn you when you might see a rendering error.

Answer (score 4):

There are zeros at $(2,0)$ and $(3,0)$

The other point of $(2.5,-0.00025)$ is not a zero, but may have been shown rounded; it is the minimum and also the *vertex* of the parabola

Comment: I just put 2.5 for  and got (-0.00025) Actually I got confused when I first saw this. Our maths teacher recently taught us about identities, when all the coefficients are zero. So I was just playing with different numbers, wondering what would happen if all the coefficients became very small but still non-zero. I was so startled when I saw this expression, that I forgot to plug 2.5 for x and check if I got zero, lol. And thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not. Possibly a rounding error. Zeroes for that polynomial are at $x=2$ and $x=3$
There is a minimum at $x=2.5$, hitting the value -0.00025, which is also a possible reason why the point is highlighted

Comment: Plugging in 2.5 for $x$ gets us ($0.01225$ - $0.01250$), which is not equal to zero. I just noticed it. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

It cannot have more than 2 zeros. The fundamental theorem of algebra tells us it has exactly 2 zeros, possibly repeated.
The zeros of 
$$
c(x^2-5x+6)
$$
where $c$ is any (non-zero) constant, are the same as the zeros of,
$$
(x^2-5x+6)
$$
What you are running in to is the real-life practicalities of using a computational tool to determine the zeros. The plot you show displays the $y$ values with no decimal places.  Things to try

[1] Can you display the $y$ to more decimal places?

[2] Can you change the scales of the plot to get a better look?